# Calculating the contours of a 3D heightmap?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, 2d, gis, contour

I am looking for a function or example to produce a list of lines representing contours at a specific height within a heightmap.

Eg,

```
Lines[] = GetContours(Heights[512,512], HeightValue)
```

Where Heights is a 512x512 array of floating point values, HeightValue is the height at which the contour should be drawn. Heights may contain multiple lines for that specific height (eg a Saddle, or island chain)

Does anyone have or know where to get an algorithm to generate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're actually trying to do is to draw an iso-line.
see [my question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231642/drawing-an-iso-line-of-a-2d-implicit-scalar-field) it a while ago.
[The link given](http://web.archive.org/web/20140718130446/http://members.bellatlantic.net/~vze2vrva/thesis.html) in one of the answers was very helpful.

Comment: The link to the thesis is dead (404).

Comment: Helpful _how_? Did you end up implementing the thesis' approach completely from scratch? (because that's not helpful at all for people who come to SO for programming help =D)

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithm is [marching squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

a) Find which polygons have vertices above&below the height you're interested in.

b) Intersect the edges of those polygons with the plane to get lines on the plane.

c) Join the lines together in strips.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Srtm2Osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/index.php/Srtm2Osm), a tool I've made to generate contours from NASA's SRTM data. You can find the algorithm in the C# code.